# Is it possible to have more than one simultaneous connection to the specified IoT Watson device via the MQTT client?

Tags: ibm-watson

A unique client id having a specific format (d:organizationID:deviceType:deviceID) is used for connection to MQTT in IoT Watson.
It looks that only one unique MQTT connection is allowed per client id to a specific device.

For some cases is required to have more than one simultaneous MQTT connection to the specific device inside the organization account,  e.g., in the case of scaling of services integrated with the IBM Watson platform (i.e. clustering).

The question will be, is there the possibility to have more than one simultaneous MQTT connection to the specific device inside the organization account?
For example, by having the possibility to generate a client id or some part of the client id?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for devices. The clientId has to be unique as you said and so any existing connection using that clientId would be disconnected when the new connections is made. I am not quite sure I understand the use case you mention with clustering, as the one connection should be fine for a device.

If you have an application rather than a device then you can create a "Scalable Application" as mentioned here https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/watson-iot-platform?topic=applications-communicating-mqtt which extends the clientId.